# function to iterate through each header dictated by a list

Tags: python, pandas, function, pypdf

I have a function that I want to run for each element in the list `models`. These elements correlate to a header in and excel document with models up to model10.

What I'd like it to do now is read what models are needed, then iterate the function for each of the models dictated in `models`. So it reads the `models` as the header, then creates a PDF document with each of the files from the excel under the header mentioned.

My dataframe looks like this:

```
   model1      model2    model3     
0  File1.pdf   File3.pdf File2.pdf
1  File2.pdf   nan.pdf   File2.pdf
2  File3.pdf   nan.pdf   File2.pdf
```

```
models = ["model1","model2","model3"]
def merge_pdf(models):
        merger = PdfFileMerger()
        for col_name in models:
            for index, row in df.iterrows():
                merger.append(row[col_name])
        merger.write(f"Test({col_name}).pdf")
        merger.close()
merge_pdf(models)
```

My expected output:
3 separate PDF files that is created following rows under the header, so one PDF pack that contains File1, File2 & File3, another with just File3 and so on.

Error I get: "AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'seek'"

Comment: What error did you encounter with the above?

Comment: AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'seek'

Comment: Do you normally pass strings to `PdfFileMerger` like that? It looks like it does [support strings](https://github.com/claird/PyPDF4/blob/master/pypdf/merger.py#L191), but you could follow [this example](https://github.com/LeoFCardoso/pdf2pdfocr/blob/master/pdf2pdfocr.py#L897) and pass an already read file

Comment: I'm trying to run the function only for specific headers in a "master" excel with multiple headers. I'm not as familiar with how to do that.

Comment: In the example above, you pass the string from the excel file into the file reader, and then pass that to the merger

`merger.append(PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(row[col_name], strict=False))`

Comment: I tried this out and I'm still getting `AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'seek'`

Comment: My suggestion would then be to strip it down to functional pieces. Can append one file explicitly? For-loop through 2 in an array? It could be that your df is handling files as floats for some reason.